# Can a 2 million dollar perpetuity sustain 100k/month

Tags: investment-strategies

Based on a 2 million dollar donation, Is there a perpetuity that would be self sustaining to keep a small individual long term care residential house afloat? Or what would be another option given the monthly expenses being approximately $100k.

Comment: "**monthly** expenses being approximately **$100k.**"  That's $1.2 **MILLION** per year.  Did you accidentally type an extra 0 in that number?

Comment: 5% (a quite reasonable yield *now*) of 2 million is 100,000.

Comment: 2 millions will run out within less than 2 years at that draw rate even with the currently reasonable  *annual* yield rate of 5%.

Comment: @RonJohn 5% is a reasonable *annual* return. The OP needs to make 5% *per month*, or closer to *80%* per year.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie and that's *huge*, which is why I asked whether she made a typo.

Answer (score 3):

Common retirement planning rule of thumb is to aim for savings of 25 times what your budgeted yearly expenses will be. If one assumes you can get 4% return (after inflation) on your savings, that means that you can draw that 4% per year "forever" without reducing the principal.

This is subject to some caveats, due to year to year variation in returns and inflation, but it has some safety allowance built into it; average market rate of return has historically been closer to 8% than 4%.

So it you really want to draw $100k/month "perpetually", you want to start with $37M. If you mean $10k a month, you want $3.7M before you can live solely off that. $100k/year (most likely what you intended to write) would be about $2.5M.

My spending is considerably less than that despite living in a relatively expensive part of the country, since the house is paid off and I live an upper middle-class lifestyle rather than trying to pretend I'm rich. By this rule of thumb, I could have retired at a net worth of about $1.9M and it would be pretty darned likely to last "forever", at least until I went into end-of-life care. But I wanted to keep the house's equity as a crisis reserve, so my goal was to have $1.9M in savings and investments in addition to the house. And I'm assuming that 10 years of end-of-life care will burn off most of the cash, leaving not much more than the house.

Again, this is all hand-waving in lieu of doing the right thing: figuring out what your budget is going to be in today's dollars, predicting how you expect it to increase over time due to inflation and such, calculating how much that actually comes to in spending, deciding how much return on your retirement funds you can expect, and determining whether the latter can cover the former.

There are software tools out there which can help with this. I use some of Quicken's planning functions to sanity check my conclusions, but I haven't attempted to compare it to others so that is an observation, not a recommendation.

Caveat: There's a common claim that expenses go down in retirement. That is not necessarily true; commuting goes down but things you were getting as employment benefits go up, as does medical cost over time. On the other hand, retirement also lowers your tax bracket, and may mean more of your income is being taken from tax-advantaged savings, which can help. Again, run the numbers to get a sense of the range of real answers for your foreseeable cases.

Comment: "Common retirement planning rule of thumb is to aim for savings of 20 times what your budgeted yearly expenses will be." That's very courageous - I heard of 25 to 33 times - that would be 4% or even only 3%. The Trinity Study suggests 4%, 3% would be more conservative. 5% can lead to trouble.

Comment: Actually, I think 25x is closer to what I actually used. I'll edit.

Comment: 25x (4% SWR) is not a _perpetual_ withdrawal rate - it's only a rate which makes it likely for the person to die before their money run out. But the portfolio is expected to be drawn down at that rate.

Comment: @void_ptr: . Agreed, 5% is a rule-of-thumb probably -safe-for-life value, not perpetual, and assumes that your rate of return exceeds sum of rate of draw and rate of inflation. For better advice, run real numbers. But question was asking about ballpark expectations.

Comment: Seriously, nothing is guaranteed perpetual unless you buy an inflation-protected annuity, which basically means paying someone else a significant amount to accept that risk and thus costs even more. I am expecting  that my earnings will approach keeping pace with spending and inflation over the next several decades , but run your own numbers.

Comment: (And even then, it's only as guaranteed as the company backing it is. But that's often good enough.)